# LINQ Average function arguments

Tags: asp.net, linq, average

I'm stumped on how to get my average UI layer function working. First, here is the function in my Data Access Layer which appears to be working fine:

```
public class AvgReviewInfo
{
   public int AvgReviewId { get; set; }
   public int AvgNum { get; set; }
   public double AvgTags { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<AvgReviewInfo> getAvgCuisine(int RestID)
{
   // Return the count of the average number of reviews for a specific restaurant ID
   var AvgCuisine = from REVIEW in db.REVIEWs
                    where REVIEW.REST_ID == RestID
                    group REVIEW by REVIEW.REVIEW_ID into t
                    select new AvgReviewInfo { 
                             AvgReviewId = t.Key, 
                             AvgNum = t.Count(),
                             AvgTags = t.Average(c => c.FOOD_ID)   };

   return AvgCuisine;
}
```

I trying to populate a text box with the AVERAGE in my UI layer using the the following code:

```
BLgetDetails obj2 = new BLgetDetails();
var AvgCuisine = obj2.getAvgCuisine(restid);
lblAvgReviews.Text = AvgCuisine.Average().ToString();
```

I don't understand from the hints by intellisense what arguments are needed. I know this must be something simple ;O((

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `AvgCuisine` is a *collection* of `AvgReviewInfo` - is that really what you want? If so, what sort of average do you want - the average of averages? (I'd also encourage you to start following .NET naming conventions...)

Comment: So what is your question and problem?

Comment: What does the Intellisense say?

Comment: Just getting started with LINQ & Lambda expressions.  I will go back to my text and see if I can figure this out.  BTW, I'm new to programming and building this project on my own.  Is there a source for this syntax standard that you would recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Func<T,int>` or `Func<T,double>` overloads of IEnumerable.Average need you to supply a lambda function which selects which field of "AvgReviewInfo" you want to calculate the average of.

Basically you are supplying a function that does something for every item in the collection.

For example, to calculate the average of the AvgNum field you would use

```
lblAvgReviews.Text = AvgCuisine.Average(a=>a.AvgNum).ToString();
```

Where the left hand side `a =>` means literally *given an individual **AvgReviewInfo** which we are calling **a***, the right hand side `a.AvgNum` means return the value of **AvgNum**

This lamba function is run over every item in the IEnumerable and the resulting average is calculated.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks so much for adding the background information as well.  I'm such a newbie, I really appreciate your help.  Regards~